# Unable to select VPC when creating an RDS instance

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, rds

When creating an RDS instance in my brand new non-default VPC, I am unable to select it from the VPC drop-down, preventing me completing the new instance wizard. Is there something I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, it turns out you need to create an RDS Subnet Group to link your VPC to RDS before it's available for selection when creating an instance.